# elseif line being executed even if the condition is fulfilled

Tags: php, html

**PHP**

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['calculate'])) {
        $seller= $_POST['seller'];
        $buyer= $_POST['buyer'];
        $amount= $_POST['amount'];
        $rate= $_POST['tax_rate'];



            if (empty(($seller && $buyer) && ($amount && $rate) )){
                echo $warning= "Please full out the fields properly";
            }elseif(!is_int($amount && $rate)){
                echo $warning ="please input numbers on Tax Rate & Amount";


            }
    }
}
```

I can't understand if the error is in html or is in php?

The tax amount must be an integer value but why even being passed the condition the form does not process.

**HTML**

```
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styletax.css">
</head>
<body>
<--! tax calculator-->
<div class="taxform">
    <fieldset>
        <form action="calculator_processor.php" method="post">
            <div class="formcontent">
                <label for="sellername">Seller Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="sellername" name="seller"></input>

                <label for="buyerrname">Buyer Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="buyername" name="buyer"></input>

                <label for="Product Type">Product Type</label>
                <select name="product">
                    <option value="jeans">Jeans</option>
                    <option value="tshirt">Tshirt</option>
                    <option value="sunglass">Sunglass</option>
                    <option value="mobile">Mobile</option>
                    <option value="other">Other</option>
                </select> <br/>
                <?php //echo $warning; ?>
                <label for="money">Total Amount</label>
                <input type="text" id="money" name="amount"></input>
                <?php //echo $warning; ?>
                <label for="taxrate">Tax Rate</label>
                <input type="text" name="tax_rate" id="taxrate"></input>
                <div class="btn">
                    <input type="submit" name="calculate" class="button" value="Calculate Tax"></input>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

    </fieldset>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try `}elseif( !is_int($amount) && !is_int($rate) ){`

Comment: And, what you are expecting from this line `if (empty(($seller && $buyer) && ($amount && $rate) )){` ?

Comment: `empty(($seller && $buyer) && ($amount && $rate) )` makes no sense. you're testing a boolean true/false for emptiness... that means if the `&&` all evaluate to true, you get a boolean true, which is **NOT** empty.

Comment: `$amount && $rate` can never be an integer. `&&` always returns a boolean.

Comment: Hey there I really was expecting to check that the user does not submit the form empty? I guess i had a bad sense there?

Comment: if (empty(($seller && $buyer) && ($amount && $rate) )){this line was meant the user to prevent filling empty form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`is_int($amount && $rate)` is not testing whether both `$amount` and `$rate` are integers. It's testing whether the value of the expression `$amount && $rate` is an integer. `&&` is a boolean `AND`, it returns `true` if both operands are truthy, otherwise it returns `false`. Since the result is a boolean, not an integer, `is_int()` will always return `false` for this.

Another problem is that form inputs are always strings, not numbers. If you want to test whether a string looks like a number, you must use `is_numeric`, not `is_int`. So the code should be:

```
elseif (!is_numeric($amount) || !is_numeric($rate))
```

to test each variable.

Similarly, if you want to test if multiple variables are empty, use

```
if (empty($seller) || empty($buyer) || empty($amount) || empty($rate)) {
    echo $warning = "Please fill out all the fields properly";
}
```

Comment: but even i try to input numbers on amount and tax why the line tax and amount should be numbers is echoed??

Comment: What are the numbers you're entering?

Comment: random numbers take 1 or anything

Comment: Make sure you're not entering decimals. 1 should work, 1.2 won't because that's a float, not an integer.

Comment: Use `is_numeric`, not `is_int`.